# Modbus Rs-485 serial communication and polling with reference to manual

Tags: rs485, modbus

I have connected my server and RS-485 using serial connection and using my computer as the client device.
I'm able to poll but I cant figure out which registers I'm polling as shown in image 1.
I tried to pull the registers as shown in the manual (image 2) but I can pull only one register at a time.

Is there any way to poll all the registers I need in the same time?

[image: modbus connected to Rs-485]
[image: pulling address i need]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is related directly to a windows application called *Modbus Poll*. It is Modbus master simulator.

Anyway, you are actually reading first 10 registers in your first screenshot. The second column name (next to *Alias*) contains the *Start Address* of registers you wish to read (in your case it's 0). And then you have your quantity of registers that you wish to read (10 in your example) represented in the table.

In this application to change *start addresss* and *quantity* you should go to *Setup->Read/Write Definition* and there select your slave device ID, function code (choose function code either 0x03 or 0x04 to read holding registers or input registers, they may not be the same in some devices), start address and quantity.

Comment: GAttuso thanks answering i cant access all the registers in the same time if i give address 3 it only displays all the register that has this address but need all of them in the same page as shown in the image 1.

Comment: Mike, the registers can only be read in a contigious blocks. And for each address there is exactly one register. That means if you send request with start address = 3 and quantity = 4, you will get values of registers with address 3,4,5, and 6.